# Computer doesn't receive proper sustain pedal MIDI signals from digital piano?

Tags: piano, midi, keyboard, digital-piano, keyboard-pedals

When I connect my piano to my computer and press the sustain pedal, it just plays a C note. (Garageband, and Musescore.)
I have an Arius YDP-161 digital piano and a MIDI to USB converter. I use a MacBook Air 2015.

[image]

I searched a bit and saw that people with this converter had the same issues. These cheap MIDI converters can't send the proper MIDI signals because of poor circuiting.

Comment: Make & model of converter, or a picture would be useful. If it's one of those 10 buck Chinese things with a "what the heck clef is that" symbol on it, throw it away & buy one with a name you have heard of.

Comment: Are you sure it's a C note and not an E? https://www.reddit.com/r/piano/comments/1up7x2/sustain_pedal_plays_note_when_midi/  (reason given: you bought a $5 USB MIDI converter from Amazon)

Comment: As @Tetsujin said, if you have the same USB MIDI converter than [this post](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/100298/properly-set-up-midi-to-usb) you can be pretty sure it is its fault…

Comment: @Tetsujin Oh my god that is literally the one I have. "What the heck clef". I can't afford other converters. (I'm not joking. Inflation is huge here.) Isn't there any way to fix it without having to buy a new one?

Comment: I don't think so. It's inherent in the stunningly poor quality of the chip inside.